# How to print a substring in C

Tags: c

simple C question here!
So I am trying to parse through a string lets say: 1234567W

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //pointer to open file
    FILE *op;
    //open file of first parameter and read it "r"
    op = fopen("TestCases.txt", "r");
    //make an array of 1000
    char x[1000];
    char y[1000];
    //declare variable nums as integer
    int nums;
    //if file is not found then exit and give error
    if (!op) {
        perror("Failed to open file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        while (fgets(x, sizeof(x), op)) {
            //pounter to get the first coordinate to W
            char *p = strtok(x, "W");
            //print the first 3 digits of the string 
            printf("%.4sd\n", p);
                
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

My output so far shows: "123d" because of the "%.4sd" in the printf function.
I now need to get the next two numbers, "45". Is there a regex expression I can use that will allow me to get the next two digits of a string?
I am new to C, so I was thinking more like "%(ignore the first 4 characters)(print next 2 digits)(ignore the last two digits)"

input: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbE5o.png)

output: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3JEA.png)

Please let me know.
Thanks all.

Comment: Please show actual input and output. I don't understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist input and output are both shown already.

Comment: @madPhysicist sorry about that, I posted pics of input and output.

Comment: Please don't post pics. Format console text as code.

Comment: Why are you not calling strtok again? Or use sscanf?

Answer (score 0):

`printf("Next two: %.2s\n", p + 4);` should work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //pointer to open file
    FILE *op;
    //open file of first parameter and read it "r"
    op = fopen("TestCases.txt", "r");
    //make an array of 1000
    char x[1000];
    char y[1000];
    //declare variable nums as integer
    int nums;
    //if file is not found then exit and give error
    if (!op) {
        perror("Failed to open file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        while (fgets(x, sizeof(x), op)) {
            //pounter to get the first coordinate to W
            char *p = strtok(x, "W");
            //print the first 3 digits of the string
            printf("%.4sd\n", p);
            printf("Next two: %.2s\n", p + 4);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Side note: I added a missing `stdio.h` include. Please turn on compiler warnings, since this error would've been caught by them.

Comment: thank you so much! this is the exact answer I was looking for.